# Trouble with gif files in a list in Python with Pycharm

Tags: python, image, list, graphics

So I've been trying to run this code on the computers at school and my laptop at home and I keep getting the error message saying:
 'list index is out of range'
But it runs fine on my instructor's laptop, it prints out a code of the first image.  Everything is the same but mine won't run, we're both using the same interpreter.
...what's going on here?

Running through PyCharm 4.5.4 with Python 3.5.0:

```
   import os  
   import graphics  
   from glob import glob

    def get_images(subFolderName):
      pathName = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), subFolderName, '*.gif')
      listOfFileNames = glob(pathName)
      return listOfFileNames

    list = get_images("SampleProjectGifs")
    listOfImages = []

    for index in list:
      listOfImages.append(graphics.Image(graphics.Point(50, 50), index))

    print(listOfImages[0])
```

Comment: In which OS are you getting the error? Is it the same as the OS on the machines where the code works?

Comment: print( listOfImages[0] ) is the line the error occurs on.  Also should note that there are 40 .gif files in folder SampleProjectGifs which are in the same directory as my project.

Comment: Hey @Deanbean, check my answer below. It should solve your problem. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting any image files. So your list is empty - listOfImages. That is the reason why your are receiving OutOfIndex error.

try inspecting this line of code - `listOfFileNames = glob(pathName)`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and it is returning an empty list.

Try replacing your `get_images` method with:

```
def get_images(subFolderName):
    pathName = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), subFolderName, '*.gif')
    listOfFileNames = glob(pathName)
    return listOfFileNames
```

Comment: I tried that and it returns an error code for the print statement saying that the 'list index is out of range' still

Comment: Which operational system are you using?

Comment: Could you also give more details about the folder structure? Do you have something like script and `SampleProjectGifs` in the same folder?

Comment: The folder was within another folder which I eliminated and now the code runs.  Thank you!